# is it possible to install Pentaho's community Edition without stepping on an Enterprise evaluation license?

Tags: pentaho

Is it possible to install Pentaho's Community edition without stepping on an Enterprise install? Are there any special instructions to do this or things I should be aware of? how do you point the second install to the KTR files that you have already built?

Answer (score 2):

Community edition can live along-side an Enterprise trial.  If you are using a file in both environments, you've got to make sure that they do not step on each other, just like if you were to run two CE installs at once.

If you're also using the BI Server, you'll need to make sure that you're running each version on different ports.